# Fine Uploader to S3 Folder

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, upload, fine-uploader

Does anyone know if it's possible to upload to a folder inside an S3 bucket using Fine Uploader? I have tried adding a '\foldername' to the request endpoint but had no luck with that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

S3 doesn't have folders.  Some UIs (such as the one in the AWS console) and higher-level APIs may provide this concept, as an abstraction, but S3 doesn't have any native understanding of folders, only keys.  You can create any key you want and pass it along to Fine Uploader S3, it will store that file given that specific key.  For example, "folder1/subfolder/foobar.txt" is a perfectly valid key name.  By default, Fine Uploader generates a UUID and uses that as your object's key name, but you can easily change this by providing an `objectProperties.key` value, which can also be a function.  See the [S3 `objectProperties` option in the documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/options-s3.html#objectproperties-option) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
    // ...
    objectProperties: {
        key: function(fileId) {
            return 'folder/within/bucket/' + this.getUuid(fileId);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#fineuploader-s3").fineUploaderS3({
    // ....
    objectProperties: {
        key: function (fileId) {

            var filename = $('#fineuploader-s3').fineUploader('getName', fileId);
            var uuid = $('#fineuploader-s3').fineUploader('getUuid', fileId);
            var ext = filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1); 

           return  'folder/within/bucket/' + uuid + '.' + ext;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you provide some explanation as to what the code is doing?

Comment: No need to use jQuery here, especially since the question is not tagged with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the path before upload to the server:

```
uploader.on('submit', (id) => {   
  const key = s3Uploader.methods.getUuid(id)   
  const newkey = 'folder/within/bucket/' + key   
  uploader.methods.setUuid(id, newkey) 
})
```