# react-fine-uploader S3 upload using dynamic filename

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

### Background

I am integrating creating a react app using react-fine-uploader to upload directly to an S3 bucket, I don't have any server-side code.  I've been able to upload to my bucket using the regular uuid that react-fine-uploader creates out of the box.  What I'd now like to do is dynamically create the file name so that I can write the files to s3 "folders".

### Problem

I know I can configure my uploader.options.objectProperties.key, and pass it a function such as:

```
var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
    // ...
    objectProperties: {
        key: function(fileId) {
            return 'folder/within/bucket/' + this.getUuid(fileId);
        }
    }
});
```

(Taken from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19988879/fine-uploader-to-s3-folder))

This is fine when you want to handle values that you can get from the file/uploader (such as the uuid), and with other static info.  What I want is to include a folder name that has been passed to this component from elsewhere.  Here's my attempt so far:

```
//imports...
const uploader = new FineUploaderS3({
    options: {
        //other options...
        objectProperties: {
            key: function(fileId) {
                return folderName + '/' + this.getUuid(fileId);
            }
        }
    }
});

var folderName = null;

class FileUpload extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        folderName = this.props.folderName;
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <Gallery uploader={uploader} />
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default FileUpload;
```

Currently this adds this into a folder in s3 called "null", but I am successfully passing this component the folderName in props.

What do I need to do to connect these things up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the value of the `fileUpload` prop when `FileUpload` is initially rendered? As written, this will only set the `fileUpload` variable in the scope the `FineUploaderS3` instance has access to when the component is initially rendered. If the `fileUpload` prop is given a value later, you may need to use `componentWillReceiveProps()` to update `folderName` when that happens (and you can only have one `FileUpload` component, as the last one to render will win).

---

Another approach is to create objects which depend on a component's props or state as part of its lifecycle and store them on the component instance itself, e.g.:

```
class FileUploadComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    // We can't use an arrow function for the key function below as we need to
    // access both this component's props and the FileUploader instance within it
    let component = this
    this.uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
      // ...
      objectProperties: {
        key(fileId) {
          return `${component.props.folderName}/${this.getUuid(fileId)}`
        }
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <Gallery uploader={this.uploader}/>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes Jonny, this worked.  Thanks.  Knew there was something about getting the uploader scoped appropriately to have access to the passed prop value.

Comment: This will however not work. First the props come undefined then they become populated. React will first render with undefined and then try to render with the new defined props.

The uploader won't be changed in the 2nd rerender and will stay with the undefined props making the uploader itself not usable. DO NOT put the uploader in  your constructor, make it a function outside the component.

However the solution to save the context in component and  make key a function answers the question even though it breaks the uploader. Keep the solution in the external function.